# Creating a SOAP webservice without a namespace for the parameter

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

First here is what I want to do:
I want to create a webservice that calls a java function `void doSomething(ParamType value);` when it receives the SOAP message

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <paramType>
            <elem>test</elem>
        </paramType>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Note the missing namespace of paramType.

I created the following class to contain the doSomething function:

```
@WebService(name = "doSomethingPort", targetNamespace = "http://www.tim.org/nsClass/")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public class DoSomethingImpl {

    @WebMethod(action = "http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1")
    @Oneway
    public void doSomething(
            @WebParam(name = "paramType", targetNamespace = "http://www.tim.org/nsParam/", partName = "value") 
            ParamType value) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hallo Welt");
    }
}
```

and the following class to hold the parameter:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", namespace="http://www.tim.org/nsXMLType/")
@XmlRootElement(name="paramType", namespace="http://www.tim.org/nsXMLRootElem/")
public class ParamType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String elem;

    public String getElem() {
        return elem;
    }

    public void setElem(String value) {
        this.elem = value;
    }
}
```

The webservice is started with:

```
Endpoint.publish( "http://localhost:8090/services", new DoSomethingImpl());
```

The result after some testing is:
This webservice accepts messages in which the paramType has a namespace: `<nsp:paramType xmlns:nsp="http://www.tim.org/nsParam/">`

When I leave the targetNamepace declaration on the parameter he uses the targetNamespace on the DoSomethingImpl class (the `http://www.tim.org/nsClass/`)

Removing the namespace there causes the webservice to create a namespace from his package name.

Does anybody has an Idea how I get a webservice accepting that message?
I would prefer to repair/reconfigure my existing webservice, but I would accept other ways to accept the message and call the doSomething function.

Comment: Maybe `null` works as you need. Did you tried this?

Comment: `"null"` (with quotes) creates a namespace "null"
and `null` doesn't compile